# iOS Adhoc Distribution OTA: Bundle version in plist

Tags: ios, plist, adhoc, ota

I am distributing my .ipa via Xcode 4.5 archiving mechanism over the air to my testers. Found out, that earlier the automaticly generated plist-file contained the bundle-version of the current build.

I'd like to get this bundle-version into my plist automatically, when exporting the archive to my desktop, because thats a main action I do very often.

Is there an easy way to add the bundle version to the plist automatically or do I have to write a shell script, which opens the .ipa and reads the information to write it to the plist later?

I want to use this, to send my beta testers reminders to update the beta app, when the version differs to the installed bundle version.

Any ideas or hints?

Comment: If you check the `Save for Enterprise Distribution` checkbox while saving .ipa from Organizer, you will still get an automatically generated .plist file that includes build version, so I'm not sure I understand what you are asking here.

Comment: I exactly use the "saving for Enterprise Distribution" with newest beta XCode 4.5. The plist generated looks not contains the bundle-version...

   <key>metadata</key>
   <dict>
    <key>bundle-identifier</key>
    <string>my.bundleIdentifier</string>
    <key>kind</key>
    <string>software</string>
    <key>title</key>
    <string>Name</string>
   </dict>


(Sorry, don't know how to format as code in stackoverflow)

Comment: That's weird. Did you check if your app's Info.plist file contains bundle version? You can wrap code into `\`` chars, but it will always be single line in comments.

Comment: My bundle version in the App-Info.plist is `1.4.0 (x) Dev`.

Have you tried it also with XCodes 4.5 Preview version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it!

Till now I used `CFBundleVersion` for my version string, but `CFBundleShortVersionString` is set into plist, which was empty the whole time.

Thank you for your support. Hope other people will fix this issues faster from now. :-)

Answer (score 1):

> The bundle version string specifies the build version number of the bundle. This value is a monotonically increased string, **comprised of one or more period-separated integers**.

There is your problem. You can't have parentheses or letters in your bundle version, only numbers and dots.

Comment: Hum, I was hopeful, readingt your msg. I set my version to `1.4.0` now, but same result. No Bundle-version in the plist.

Thx for the version hint at all. I will mind it in future.

Any further ideas, whats going wrong here?